# Where do I find a linux 3.9 kernel?

Tags: sound, kernel

I have ubuntu 13.04 desktop installed and I've been reading about kernel 3.9s release yesterday. My issue is that I have no sound output with HDMI, something the new kernel apparently fixes. In reading, I've also come across kernels built for specific processors (I have an i5 on this laptop).  I guess my question is there a place to get this 3.9 kernel for my i5 processor for install in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a place you can download test build of kernels created by Ubuntu Kernel Team. It's called Kernel PPA. If you want to give kernel 3.9 a try please go to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9-raring/ and download the following files:

If you're running the 64 bit version of Ubuntu:

```
linux-headers-3.9.0-030900_3.9.0-030900.201304291257_all.deb
linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic_3.9.0-030900.201304291257_amd64.deb
linux-image-3.9.0-030900-generic_3.9.0-030900.201304291257_amd64.deb
```

Or if you're running the 32 bit version of Ubuntu:

```
linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic_3.9.0-030900.201304291257_i386.deb
linux-headers-3.9.0-030900_3.9.0-030900.201304291257_all.deb
linux-image-3.9.0-030900-generic_3.9.0-030900.201304291257_i386.deb
```

Then install those files by typing following command in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Please note however that installing a kernel from outside distribution repository is **very likely** to **break compatibility** of some software/drivers e.g. VirtualBox, VMware or NVIDIA/AMD **GPU drivers** and **is not supported**.

Comment: thank you for this information.  can you tell me anything or point me in the right direction for a specific i5 build of this kernel?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you won't notice any difference between kernels built for Intel i5 CPU and a generic x86_64 build.